# In how many ways can $12$ different balls go into $3$ different boxes so that in every box there are $4$ balls?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I need help with this question:

In how many ways can $12$ different balls go into $3$ different boxes so that in every box there are $4$ balls?

The answer should be $34650$.

Thank you.

Comment: $$12!/(4!)^{3}$$

Comment: There are $\binom {12}{4}$ ways to populate the first box...then $\binom {8}{4}$ ways to populate the second...so....

Comment: As @Mattos said you have $12!$ ways to put your balls in the boxes, but the contents of a box are the same whichever permutation you make in its elements so you have to divide by $4!$ three times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turns out to be a multinomial coefficient:

$$\binom{12}{4,4,4} = \frac{12!}{4!\,4!\,4!}$$

Another way to see it is to select 4 for the first box, 4 for the second, and 4 for the last:

$$\binom{12}{4} \cdot \binom{12 - 4}{4} \cdot \binom{12 - 8}{4}
  = \frac{12!}{4! 8!} \cdot \frac{8!}{4! 4!} \cdot \frac{4!}{4! 0!}
  = \frac{12!}{4!\,4!\,4!}$$

Answer (score 0):

The number of ways to permute $12$ different balls is $12!$.

If we draw an example we get something like:

$$6312|A4B9|5C87$$

But each box has $4!=24$ combinations, so we need to divide by $4!^3$.

So the final answer is $\dfrac{12!}{4!^3}=34650$.

Answer (score 0):

When$ m $things are to be equally placed in  $n$ things then total ways are $\frac{m!}{(m/x)!)^3}$  $x$ is the number of equal divisions here as 12 balls are equally divided then total ways are $\frac{12!}{(4!)^3}$